# Firestore rules debug(...) function not working

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I have a Firebase emulator set up on my local machine, and I've connected JS client and admin SDKs to test the security rules. Reading/writing data seems to be working properly, and requests are allowed/denied in accordance with my local `firestore.rules` file. However, nothing is being added to `firestore-debug.log` after data is modified in Firestore, despite `debug` being added to the rules file. Is there any reason this function wouldn't be working?

`firestore.rules` (simplified for testing)

```
rules_version = '2'

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read;
            allow write: if debug(request.auth) != null;
        }
    }
}
```

`firebase.json`

```js
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```